# Search HTML and ScrollTo

Tags: javascript, html, search, input

So I've got a list a document with 2000 plus entries. I want to add some form of search functionality. I have an input bar, obviously, but how would I go about writing the javascript that searches the page and the ScrollTo's to that location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.find) and [range.findText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536422%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
<input id="search" >
<input type="button" value="search" onclick="fx(document.getElementById('search'))">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function fx(o)
{ 
  var _o=o;
  if(window.find)
  { 
    _o.style.visibility='hidden';
    setTimeout(function(){window.find(_o.value);_o.style.visibility='visible';},10);
  }
  else if(document.body.createTextRange)
  {
    var rng=document.body.createTextRange();
        rng.findText(o.value);
        rng.select();
  }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a newbie, how would I go about getting this from the text returned of an input form?

Comment: I added an example above. Please note: Unfortunately this didn't work in Opera, because Opera doesn't support one of both methods.

Comment: Worked perfectly in Chrome (thank you), but didn't work on the target browser (mobile Safari on the iPhone). Thanks so much however!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through elements you want to search. Step recursively through child nodes and search each one with a regex, probably something like `/\bTERM\b/`.

When you find one, locate its offset position, and then `scrollTo()` that offset.